# Is it possible to add a layer in a keras model that is only applied during inference?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, quantization

I am trying to quantize a custom keras model myself. Next to the weights I also want to quantize activations to have all fixed point values for the computationally intensive convolutional layers. Can I add a custom layer to my model that is only used for infernce and not during training? I want to train at full precision and only quantize post-training and for activations during infernce obviously.

Another alternative might be to save the weights after training to a .h5 file and build a similar model that includes the activation quantization layers. But I am guessing keras would be thrown off if the model structure is not exactly the same.

I am just getting started with ML and TF. Thanks so much for any tips!

Comment: Why don't you create a new model for inference time which includes the layers of your training model as well as other inference-specific layers you would like? Could you provide a minimal example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I figured it out, I thought one could only load the weights from a file into a model of the exact same structure but as long as one does not add any layers containing weights it works as expected. Thanks so much!